# Como fazer um programa diferenciar numeros pares e impares em python

Tags: python-3.x

olá boa noite gostaria de aprender como fazer um programa diferenciar numeros pares de impares

tenho que aprender sobre o que ?

Comment: Primeiramente, recomendo você aprender a utilizar o site da forma correta para evitar qualquer possível constrangimento. Você consegue fazer isso de maneira bem fácil acessando o [tour]. O tour te dá uma visão bem geral de como o site funciona e, se quiser informações mais detalhadas, acesse a [help].

Comment: Segundamente, você deve estudar, caso não saiba, qual é a definição matemática de números pares e ímpares, isto é, como diferenciar matematicamente os dois. Depois disso, busque aprender sobre [operadores matemáticos e tipos numéricos](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-complex) e [estruturas de controle](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa usar um operador chamado modulo, pois ele fará a divisão do numero, e te retornara o resto, dessa forma se um numero divido por 2 retornar zero, ele será par caso contrário ele será impar.

exemplo:

`4 % 2 == 0` o retorno dessa operação será 0 ou seja o numero é par

`5 % 2 == 0` neste caso o retorno será 1 ou seja o numero é impar

Comment: obrigado mikaellemos033